# Google Map current location crash

Tags: android, google-maps

When I try to open my application in my phone it always say "Unfortunately the Application has stopped" Can someone help me with this problem. Here is my code

I'm getting and error here setUpMapIfNeeded();

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}
```

and I'm getting and error here if (mMap == null) {

```
     private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

    private void setUpMap() { 
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker").snippet("Snippet")); 

     mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 

     LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);   
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); 
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);   
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);  
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);   
     double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();   
     double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude(); 
     LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude); 
     mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng)); 
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14)); 
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!").snippet("Consider yourself located")); 
}
```

Logcat

```
 08-20 18:04:40.626  10733-10733/com.example.rontaku.mapsdemo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rontaku.mapsdemo, PID: 10733
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.rontaku.mapsdemo/com.example.rontaku.mapsdemo.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3076)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.rontaku.mapsdemo.MapsActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded(MapsActivity.java:55)
        at com.example.rontaku.mapsdemo.MapsActivity.onResume(MapsActivity.java:47)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1198)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5530)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3066)
```

Comment: Can you post the log?

Comment: Have you added the necessary permissions?

Comment: nope, what will I add in the manifest?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>//Add this line to your manifest file

Comment: I already added that but still not working

Comment: The locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);  method is returning null as your previous known location might be null sometimes...Please check if it it is null before accessing attitude and longitude

Comment: how can I check it? sorry I'm kinda new to android studio

Comment: use if(myLocation != null){double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();   
     double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude(); }     Place the above code in place of the two lines ...double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();   
     double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

Comment: which one is line 55?

Comment: mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add these permissions to you app manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
      android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
      android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"
      android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
      android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
      android:name="your_package_name.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```

**EDIT**

```
private void setUpMap() { 
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker").snippet("Snippet")); 

     mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 

     LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);   
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); 
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);   
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);  
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL); 
if (myLocation != null)  {
     double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();   
     double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude(); 
     LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude); 
     mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng)); 
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14)); 
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!").snippet("Consider yourself located")); 
}
```

Comment: Have you added this permission android:name="your_package_name.MAPS_RECEIVE"

Comment: latitude = location.getLatitude();
 longitude = location.getLongitude();  gives me an error

Comment: can you please upload your full logcat. And now use my edit.

Comment: mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)) In private void setUpMapIfNeeded() and  setUpMapIfNeeded();  in protected void onResume()

Comment: edited my post with my full code with line 55 and 47

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to read last known location assuming there is one, but that method can give you null if there is no last known location, just change to:

```
private void setUpMap() { 
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker").snippet("Snippet")); 
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);   
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); 
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);   
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);  

    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);   
    if (null != myLocation){
        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();   
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude(); 
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude); 
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng)); 
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14)); 
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!").snippet("Consider yourself located"));
    }  
}
```

Comment: which error? If you dont' specify which error and don't put logs, it is impossible to help you!